# Nginx, React, Node & Let's Encrypt... How to point Nginx at my React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ssl, nginx

I have a React app that I need to talk to a Node server running on port 5000(via pm2) and be the root
directory of my site. The Node server fetches some data from an API and returns it to the client. Right now I have Nginx pointing right at port 5000 (I followed a tutorial to get to this point as a test).

Say my React app is located at /www/ReactApp/dist/, how do I point Nginx at that instead of my Node server on port 5000?

**Basically all I need is the contents of /www/ReactApp/dist/ served when you visit myapp.com but with the existing SSL certificate.**

The Node server.js will just run in the background and my React app will make calls to it to get data.

Here is the contents of my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name myapp.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you're basically asking how to serve static files from a directory. In order for a React app (client-side) to call the Node backend (server-side), both need to be exposed. You should add a NGINX directive like so:

```
location / {
    # Set this to the directory containing your React app's index.html.
    root /var/www/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Then, for the Node server you would keep what you have but put it at a different path, like so:

```
location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

This proxies `/api` to your Node server while serving the static contents of `/var/www` as the root route (`/`).

> NOTE: You might need to change your React configuration to reflect the `/api` addition.

Comment: Basically all I need is the contents of /var/www/ served when you visit myapp.com but with the existing SSL certificate.

Comment: You need to use the first example then, which serves a static content directory. Have a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 for more details on the NGINX directives.

Comment: @AniSkywalker what if i dont have an index.html just 2 route paths / and /api how do i adjust my nginx default.conf so that i am able to access them?