# nginx ssl + react + node, response is timeout

Tags: reactjs, ssl, nginx-config

I have made a react app, it is working fine for http protocol. now I want to enable https for this site. My node is listening on port 5000 and react working on port 3000. but I can't send commands to port 5000 where node is listening and I get time out error.
This is my nginx default configuration file in sites-enabled folder.

```
# Default server configuration
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ;

    root /var/www/html/client/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.my_domain.co my_domain.co; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }       
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
    
    location /uploads {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

what is the problem? I'm confused.

Comment: some proxy headers are missing to maintain the same session from your reactapp to the backend server, this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425690/4257943

Comment: thnks @Orecinco , but i still get time-out error

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are doing. You show a nginx config which listens on port 80 and 443, not on port 5000. It instead forwards requests to localhost ports 3000 and 5000. It is unclear what exactly you are trying and from what system and where exactly you get the error. But for example something like `https://my_domain.co:5000` is not supposed to work based on your config.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , yes that is exactly what I want to achieve. React app communicates with backend node on port 5000... how can I achieve that?

Comment: Again, it is unclear what you are doing. *" but I can't send commands to port 5000 where node is listening and I get time out error."* - Send command from where? To where? How exactly do you send these commands, i.e. tool, exact URL. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: This is the code sending data to backend node from react
`axios.post(apiAddress + `/files`, {
 uuid: fuid,
 extension: file.type,
 name: file.name
})`
and this is the apiAdress
`apiAddress: "https://my-domain.co:5000/api"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who got similar problem. I figured out that I can't send requests to some specific port (mine was port 5000) over https, instead I used nginx proxy-pass to send over requests made for /api to pass to localhost:5000 and now I got it working.